# 2nd leaflet map not rendering correctly

Tags: leaflet

I have 2 tabs, each has a leaflet map.  The first map is rendering correctly, but the second map is only displaying 1 tile (the rest grey) and the map is not centered on the correct area.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

```
  var map = L.map('tab-1').setView([latitude, longitude], 5);

  L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: '',
    accessToken: ''
  }).addTo(map);

  var map2 = L.map('tab-2').setView([latitude, longitude], 5);

  L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: '',
    accessToken: ''
  }).addTo(map2);
```

Comment: Not sure there is enough information here to help you… Would you be able to reproduce your issue online? (e.g. on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/18/))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT:

If the div that contains your 2nd map is not displayed (I guess it is within a "tab" with `displayed: none;` CSS / style), Leaflet will not be able to determine properly the map container size.

Then once your 2nd map is revealed, its container size changes, but Leaflet does not realize and still uses the previous size.

You can simply call [`map2.invalidateSize()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-invalidatesize) once that map is revealed so that Leaflet now covers the new area with tiles.

You will also need to re-set the view (using `setView` or `fitBounds` or whatever method you prefer) as it was done previously using incorrect container bounds.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/52/

(uncomment line 21 and re-run to get the correct behaviour)

---

Original answer:

Welcome to SO!

Are you really using twice `L.map(location)`, with the same `location`?

It seems to me that Leaflet would try to create 2 maps in the same container. I guess it would produce unexpected result…

This is probably a typo, is not it?

Comment: Thanks.  No, not the same location.  It's a typo.  I'll edit the post.

Comment: In case you have not found yet, I think you just need to call `map2.invalidateSize()` once you reveal your 2nd tab.