# leaflet only renders into one corner

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I have a leafletmap that only renders into one corner. When I resize the browser window, the whole map renders.

That is how I invoce the map

```
var map = L.map('map', 
{ crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857 }
).setView([105.2, 100], 6);

var tiles = L.tileLayer('http://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.{ext}', {
attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    subdomains: 'abcd',
    ext: 'png'
}).addTo(map);
```

And this is my css

```
.myContainer {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 800px;
    position: relative;
}

.map {
    width: 1024px; 
    height: 800px; 
    z-index: 0;
}
```

The `map` is wrapped in a `container`. Everything I found online regarding this problem points to *relative* sizes in the map- or its parent container. However, I have absolute sizes. I load the `.css` before the `.js` (where I initialize the map). The map will be displayed not on the startpage, but when you click on a submenue point.

Why is the map not rendered properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The map will be displayed not on the startpage, but when you click on a submenue point.

You're initializing the map on a hidden or zero-size container, which makes this question a duplicate of [2nd leaflet map not rendering correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33740130/2nd-leaflet-map-not-rendering-correctly/33740373)

The answer is the same: run `map.invalidateSize()` whenever the map should become visible, or when you change its dimensions or visibility.

Comment: Is there a reason this bug would appear when running on an iPad (IOS 8.1) but not when running in the browser?

Comment: thanks @IvanSanchez for the answer and also for the reference to the other question. The solution worked perfectly and it is perfectly explained.

Answer (score 2):

As IvanSanchez stated, map.invalidateSize() is indeed the way to go.

A useful code example for map refresh every 2 seconds in Javascript would be:

```
//Using setInterval can help the reloading or refreshing of the map itself.
  setInterval(function() {
     map.invalidateSize();
  }, 2000);
```

...Note that [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) counts time in milliseconds so for example `, 2000` are 2 seconds.

`map` in `map.invalidateSize()` is the name of the variable you set your map to when you initialized it:

**Map initialization example:**

```
var map = L.map(...
```